# Splitting integrand

Tags: calculus, integration

Consider the integral:

$\int \frac{1}{(x+3)(5+2x)}$

My teacher splits this first into two unknown fractions with two unknown numerators, namely:

$\frac{A}{(x+3)}+\frac {B}{(5+2x)}$

He then goes on to perform some sort of magic to find that A = -1 and B = 2

Knowing that my teacher is indeed NOT a magician, I come to you for assistance.

What is my teacher doing and why does it work? Thank you.

Comment: [Partial fractions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_fractions)

Comment: He's a mathemagician....

Comment: @ChristopherErnst Apparently, my professor had that written on one of his teacher evaluation forms. :)

Comment: When my students know how to do a step relatively well and I want to skip the step I wave my hands magically and they all sigh at me....  :)

Answer (score 5):

If you get a common denominator of $(x+3)(5+2x)$, then the numerators must be equal.  Thus,
$$1=A(5+2x)+B(x+3)$$
$$1=5A+2Ax+Bx+3B$$
$$0x+1=(2A+B)x+(5A+3B)$$
This means that
$$2A+B=0$$
$$5A+3B=1$$
Solve for A and B using substitution or whatever method you prefer.  Now you can solve the integral.

Answer (score 3):

Because $\frac{A}{(x+3)}+\frac {B}{(5+2x)} = \frac{A(5+2x)+B(x+3)}{(5+2x)(x+3)} = \frac{(2A+B)x+(5A+3B)}{(5+2x)(x+3)}=\frac{1}{(5+2x)(x+3)}$, this would mean that $2A+B=0$ and $5A+3B=1$. Solving these equations gives $A=-1$ and $B=2$.

Answer (score 2):

You would want to do the following $$ A/(x+3)+B/(5+2x) =1/[(x+3)(5+2x)]$$
$$ A(5+2x) + B(x+3) = 1 $$ Essentially you've multiply both by linear factors of your initial integrand. Equate the coefficients of x and 1.

$$2A+B=0$$
$$5A+3B=1$$

You will find you get the same answer as your teacher.